# Confusion about ActiveRecord associations and foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In the below example, do I have to create `employee_id` in the Office model, or is it created automatically by `db:migrate`?

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :office
end

class Office < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employee    # foreign key - employee_id
end
```

Feels like I'm missing something fundamental. I'm trying to get a basic one to many relationship working, where I can use a drop-down select of objects from the one side. Are there any good basic tuts explaining how this works?

I had to create `_id`s in all the models where I wanted this to work, but it doesn't seem right from examples I've looked at.

Comment: Have you read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html ?

Comment: Thanks for the link, I understand it better now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

two steps.

firstly, you have to create an employee_id field in the office table in the migration file. you will have something like that :

```
class CreateOffices < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :offices do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :employee_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

secondly, you have to define the association in the model. by convention, if you name the foreign_key field employee_id, you don't have to specify the name of it in the model.

```
class Office < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employee
end
```

should be enough.

Answer (score 2):

Associations in ActiveRecord comprise two parts. Hooking together the model objects (like you've done) and setting up the database. So you'll need to define the association in your migration like so:

```
def change
  create_table :offices do |t|
    # Other migrations

    t.references :employee
  end
end
```

Alternatively you can do `t.integer :employee_id` which will achieve the same end too.